# Put current theorem-like item's name/number in header

Tags: header-footer, fancyhdr

I'm using the amsthm and fancyhdr packages with the book LaTeX document class. All theorem-like items (theorem, lemma, definition, exercise, etc.) are numbered consecutively within each chapter (via the usual `\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[chapter]` declaration).

How can I put into the (recto) header the number and label of the last-numbered theorem-like item on the current page?

For example, if the last-numbered theorem-like item on a page is "Proposition 2.11", then that's what would appear in the header.

[If a recto page has no numbered item, the header should be the last-numbered item on the preceding page - or, if the preceding, verso, page has no numbered item, then on the preceding (recto) page. (I won't need any recursion deeper than that!)]

The purpose is to help the reader more readily locate the target of a reference in the text by scanning page headers instead of having to scan entire pages.

Comment: The `titleps` package seems to have tools for that. You can take a look at `§ 7, Extra marks` in the documentation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps the simplest thing of all is to use a “parallel” `\mark` system; we have learnt to be well-behaved, so we now allocate the `\marks` number with `\newmarks`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % Not necessary, but recommended.
\usepackage{etoolbox}

% \usepackage{amsthm} % doesn't call "\@opargbegintheorem", though

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\thepage}
\fancyhead[RE,LO]{\myBotmark} % "RE" just for testing purposes
\pagestyle{fancy}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section] % or "[chapter]", or whatever
\newtheorem{lemma}  {Lemma}  [section]

\makeatletter

\@ifdefinable\@my@claim@mark{\newmarks\@my@claim@mark}
\newcommand*\myMark[1]{\marks\@my@claim@mark{#1}}
\newcommand*\myBotmark{\botmarks\@my@claim@mark}

\apptocmd{\@begintheorem}     {\myMark{#1\ #2}\ignorespaces}{}{}
\apptocmd{\@opargbegintheorem}{\myMark{%
                #1\ #2%
                \ (#3)% comment this line to leave "Mickey Mouse" out
                \ignorespaces
            }}{}{}

\makeatother



\begin{document}

\section{First section}

\lipsum[1]

\begin{theorem}
    This is the first theorem of the first section.
\end{theorem}

\lipsum[2]

\begin{theorem}
    This is the second theorem of the first section.
\end{theorem}

\begin{theorem}[Donald Duck]
    This is the third theorem of the first section.
\end{theorem}

\lipsum[3-16]

\begin{theorem}
    This is the fourth theorem of the first section.
\end{theorem}

\lipsum[17]

\begin{lemma}
    This is the first lemma of the first section.
\end{lemma}

\lipsum[18]

\begin{theorem}
    This is the fifth theorem of the first section.
\end{theorem}

\lipsum[19-20]

\begin{lemma}[Uncle Scrooge]
    This is the second lemma of the first section.
\end{lemma}

\lipsum[21-32]

\begin{theorem}
    This is the sixth theorem of the first section.
\end{theorem}

\lipsum[33-36]

\begin{theorem}
    This is the seventh theorem of the first section.
\end{theorem}

\begin{lemma}
    This is the third lemma of the first section.
\end{lemma}

\begin{theorem}[Mickey Mouse]
    This is the eighth theorem of the first section.
\end{theorem}

\lipsum[37-40]

\begin{theorem}
    This is the ninth theorem of the first section.
\end{theorem}

\lipsum[41-64]

\begin{theorem}[The last one]
    This is the tenth theorem of the first section.
\end{theorem}

\lipsum[65-80]

\begin{lemma}
    This is the fourth lemma of the first section.
\end{lemma}

\begin{lemma}
    This is the fifth lemma of the first section.
\end{lemma}

\begin{lemma}
    This is the sixth lemma of the first section.
\end{lemma}

\begin{lemma}
    This is the seventh lemma of the first section.
\end{lemma}

\begin{lemma}
    This is the eighth lemma of the first section.
\end{lemma}

\begin{lemma}
    This is the ninth lemma of the first section.
\end{lemma}

\begin{lemma}[Deep breath]
    This is the tenth lemma of the first section.
\end{lemma}

\lipsum[81-84]

\begin{lemma}
    This is the eleventh lemma of the first section.
\end{lemma}

\begin{lemma}
    This is the twelfth lemma of the first section.
\end{lemma}

\begin{lemma}
    This is the thirteenth lemma of the first section.
\end{lemma}

\begin{lemma}
    This is the fourteenth lemma of the first section.
\end{lemma}

\begin{lemma}
    This is the fifteenth lemma of the first section.
\end{lemma}

\begin{lemma}[Hexadecimal deep breath]
    This is the sixteenth lemma of the first section.
\end{lemma}

% \lipsum[85-96]

\end{document}
```

Cannot post an image: compile and look at the output.

---

## Addition

Actually, the OP had made it very clear, in the question, that (s)he was using the `amsthm` package, but I overlooked this statement.  The code shown above should also work when that package is loaded, but in that case the running heads will omit the “theorem note”, that is, the optional argument given to “theorem-like environments” (*e.g.,* “Donald Duck” in the third theorem of our example) when present.  This is because the `amsthm` package does not use the standard `\@opargbegintheorem` hook.

For this as well as for other reasons, it is best to devise another patch specifically suited for the `amsthm` package, that delivers the mark in the argument of the `\deferred@thm@head` macro, which is typeset inside of `\box\@labels`; more precisely, it is emitted right before the call to either `\swappedhead` or `\thmhead`, at the very beginning of `\box\@labels`.  Note that this box is subsequently `\unhbox`ed, so the mark will wind up at the very beginning of the horizontal list that contains the theorem head, followed by the theorem claim; from there, it will migrate right after the first line of the same paragraph, that is, exactly where it belongs to.

The following code defines a command named `\IfAmsThm` that takes two arguments, and executes the code in its first argument if the `amsthm` package is loaded, and the code in its second argument if it is not.  Of course, once you have made your decision, you no longer need this device: simply delete this command and either of the two branches that does not apply.

In order to use this code in your documents you need to do only the following three things:

1. make sure to load the `etoolbox` package early in your preamble;
2. copy the code between the two comments `BEGIN WIZARDRY` and
   `END WIZARDRY` to your preamble, at a point in which *both*
   the `etoolbox` package and the `amsthm` package have already
   been loaded;
3. in the definition of your page style, put `\myBotmark` wherever
   you want the theorem reference to appear (similar to putting
   `\thepage` wherever you want the page number to appear).

Here is the amended code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % Not necessary, but recommended.
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\usepackage{amsthm} % comment or uncomment as you prefer

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\thepage}
\fancyhead[RE,LO]{\myBotmark} % "RE" just for testing purposes
\pagestyle{fancy}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section] % or "[chapter]", or whatever
\newtheorem{lemma}  {Lemma}  [section]

% A little trick to make this example work both with amsthm and without it;
% once you've made your choice, you do not need this code.
\makeatletter
    \@ifdefinable\IfAmsThm{}
    \@ifpackageloaded{amsthm}{
        \let \IfAmsThm = \@firstoftwo
    }{
        \let \IfAmsThm = \@secondoftwo
    }
\makeatother

\IfAmsThm{
    \newtheorem*{spclaim}{Special Claim}
    \theoremstyle{definition}
}{}

\newtheorem{defin}{Definition}[section]



%%%%%%%% BEGIN WIZARDRY %%%%%%%%

\makeatletter

\@ifdefinable\@my@claim@mark{\newmarks\@my@claim@mark}
\newcommand*\myMark[1]{\marks\@my@claim@mark{#1}}
\newcommand*\myBotmark{\botmarks\@my@claim@mark}

\typeout{****************************************}
\@ifpackageloaded{amsthm}{\iftrue}{\iffalse}
    \patchcmd{\@begintheorem}{% search for:
        \thm@swap\swappedhead\thmhead % more specific than before
    }{% replace with:
        \myMark{#1\@ifnotempty{#2}{\ #2}\@ifnotempty{#3}{\ (#3)}}%
        \thm@swap\swappedhead\thmhead
    }{
        \typeout{>>> Made patch specific for amsthm.}
    }{
        \typeout{>>> Patch specific for amsthm FAILED!}
    }
\else
    \apptocmd{\@begintheorem}     {\myMark{#1\ #2}\ignorespaces}{}{}
    \apptocmd{\@opargbegintheorem}{\myMark{%
                    #1\ #2%
                    \ (#3)% comment this line to leave "Mickey Mouse" out
                    \ignorespaces
                }}{}{}
    \typeout{>>> Made generic patch.}
\fi
\typeout{****************************************}

\makeatother

%%%%%%%%  END WIZARDRY  %%%%%%%%



\begin{document}

\section{First section}

\lipsum[1]

\begin{theorem}
    This is the first theorem of the first section.
\end{theorem}

\lipsum[2]

\begin{theorem}
    This is the second theorem of the first section.
\end{theorem}

\begin{theorem}[Donald Duck]
    This is the third theorem of the first section.
\end{theorem}

\IfAmsThm{
    \begin{spclaim}
        This is a special claim.
    \end{spclaim}
}{}

% \begingroup
%   \showboxbreadth = 1000
%   \showboxdepth = 10
%   \tracingonline = 1
%   \showlists
% \endgroup

\lipsum[3-16]

\begin{theorem}
    This is the fourth theorem of the first section.
\end{theorem}

\begin{defin}[Something new]
    This is the first definition of the first section.
\end{defin}

\begin{defin}
    This is the second definition of the first section.
\end{defin}

\lipsum[17]

\begin{lemma}
    This is the first lemma of the first section.
\end{lemma}

\lipsum[18]

\begin{theorem}
    This is the fifth theorem of the first section.
\end{theorem}

\lipsum[19-20]

\begin{lemma}[Uncle Scrooge]
    This is the second lemma of the first section.
\end{lemma}

\lipsum[21-32]

\begin{theorem}
    This is the sixth theorem of the first section.
\end{theorem}

\lipsum[33-36]

\begin{theorem}
    This is the seventh theorem of the first section.
\end{theorem}

\begin{lemma}
    This is the third lemma of the first section.
\end{lemma}

\begin{theorem}[Mickey Mouse]
    This is the eighth theorem of the first section.
\end{theorem}

\lipsum[37-40]

\begin{theorem}
    This is the ninth theorem of the first section.
\end{theorem}

\lipsum[41-64]

\begin{theorem}[The last one]
    This is the tenth theorem of the first section.
\end{theorem}

\lipsum[65-80]

\begin{lemma}
    This is the fourth lemma of the first section.
\end{lemma}

\begin{lemma}
    This is the fifth lemma of the first section.
\end{lemma}

\begin{lemma}
    This is the sixth lemma of the first section.
\end{lemma}

\begin{lemma}
    This is the seventh lemma of the first section.
\end{lemma}

\begin{lemma}
    This is the eighth lemma of the first section.
\end{lemma}

\begin{lemma}
    This is the ninth lemma of the first section.
\end{lemma}

\begin{lemma}[Deep breath]
    This is the tenth lemma of the first section.
\end{lemma}

\lipsum[81-84]

\begin{lemma}
    This is the eleventh lemma of the first section.
\end{lemma}

\begin{lemma}
    This is the twelfth lemma of the first section.
\end{lemma}

\begin{lemma}
    This is the thirteenth lemma of the first section.
\end{lemma}

\begin{lemma}
    This is the fourteenth lemma of the first section.
\end{lemma}

\begin{lemma}
    This is the fifteenth lemma of the first section.
\end{lemma}

\begin{lemma}[Hexadecimal deep breath]
    This is the sixteenth lemma of the first section.
\end{lemma}

% \lipsum[85-96]

\end{document}
```

As before, there’s little point in posting an image showing the result: you must compile the code yourself and check that it behaves as expected.

---

## Second Addition

See [my answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/320720/69818) to the question [Place theorem number *before* theorem label in page header](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/320483/69818) for an improved version of the code that provides compatibility with the `\swapnumbers` feature.

Comment: Something's not working there: page 7 gets header "Lemma 1.3" but should be "Theorem 1.7" (that page has Theorem 1.6 and then Theorem 1.7 as content). The others seem to be OK, accomplishing what I asked.

Comment: @murray: I get Theorem 1.8 (Mickey Mouse) as the last theorem of page 7.  Are you compiling *exactly* the source code given above?

Comment: @murray: I’ve made yet another change to the code (!), see if it works now.

Comment: The error remains if the document class option `a4paper` is left out, so that by default letter paper is used. That's the only thing I changed when I first ran the code; otherwise I directly copied from the post and pasted into the editor.

Comment: @murray: Sorry, but I’m not with you: if I remove the `a4paper` option, I get Lemma 1.3 at the bottom of page 7, as correctly indicated by the running head.  If I add a single line of text between Theorem 1.7 and Lemma 1.3, thereby pushing the latter on page 8, the running head changes to “Theorem 1.7”, as it should be.

Comment: Mazzetti: You're right: it *does* work. I missed that because I'm accustomed to numbering all theorem-like environments consecutively within a section (or chapter), rather than have separate sequences for theorems, lemmas, etc.

Comment: Why does the example comment out `\usepackage{amsthm}`?  Should it still work if `amsthm` is used?

Comment: @murray: Please see edit.

Comment: Nice generalization in latest edit!. But I haven't been able to penetrate the code in order to figure out how and where to change the header specifications so that: (1) right-hand page gets chapter or section name/number, as usual; and (2) headers can be formatted with bold, slant, sans-serif, etc.

Comment: OK, see how to change format, e.g. with: `\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\bfseries\sffamily\thepage}`, `\fancyhead[CO]{\MakeUppercase{\bfseries\sffamily\sffamily\myBotmark}}`,`\fancyhead[RE]{\bfseries\sffamily\sffamily\rightmark}`.

Comment: Next challenge for me is to see how to adapt the code when using the `memoir` class instead of `book` class.

Comment: For `memoir` class, replace the `\fancy`... commands with, e.g.: `\makeevenhead{headings}{\bfseries\sffamily\thepage}{\bfseries\sffamily\sffamily\leftmark}{}` and `\makeoddhead{headings}{}{\bfseries\sffamily\sffamily\myBotmark}{\bfseries\sffamily\thepage}`

Comment: @murray: I see that you have already found the answers to your doubts by yourself.  The principle is very simple: the “wizardry” makes another “mark” available, besides `\leftmark` and `\rightmark`, which is called `\myBotmark` and can be used exactly like the other two.  In a running head or foor (it doesn’t matter whether left or right), `\myBotmark` expands to the label of the *last* theorem-like environment that occurs on the page.  Note that `\rightmark` would *not* be adequate, because it expands to the “right-head” argument of the *first* `\markright` or `\markboth` occurring on a page.

Comment: The patch fails if there's a theorem having optional argument that includes certain math expressions. this is too long to detail here; I'm posting a separate query with a minimal example.

Comment: @murray: You should use the code given in [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/320720/69818), that should corrcetly solve all the bugs you have reported until now (thanks for doing so, BTW!).  See also my answer to your new question.

Comment: Is there a way to have two different fonts for 'Theorem #' and '(optional theorem name)' in the header? I've tried messing with the code but I get the error `argument of \@begintheorem has an extra }`.

Comment: @noibe: Do you mean, to set the various parts of the theorem title using different fonts, _e.g._, boldfacing “Theorem 1.1” and italicizing “(Weierstrass theorem)”, in the *running* head atop pages?  Yes, it is possible, although I *strongly* discourage this.  Exactly what fonts do you want to use?  Do you want the fonts used in the running head match those used for the various parts of the theorem title?  (I repeat, a very bad idea, IMHO…)

Comment: @GuM Yes, I'd like the fonts in the header to match those used in the body. I use `\textsc` (or `\scshape`) for "Theorem 1.1" and `\normalfont` for "(Weierstrass theorem)". Why exactly is it such a bad idea?