# Include in header theorem-like item name with math letter in optional argument

Tags: header-footer, theorems, fancyhdr, amsthm

In [Put current theorem-like item's name/number in header](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/319474/put-current-theorem-like-items-name-number-in-header), Gustavo Mezzetti posted an answer that allows including in the page header the current theorem-like item's name and number.

**The problem**

However, that answer fails when the `\theorem`, etc. takes an optional argument that includes certain math alphabetical characters, including `\mathbb` (but is OK for normal math letters).

I suspect that the additional fix needed is to `\protect` something, but I'm unsure what. Any suggestions?

**Test example**

This example shortens Mezzetti's code so as to eliminate irrelevancies (e.g., test as to whether `amsthm` is loaded).

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amsfonts}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\newtheorem{corollary}[theorem]{Corollary}

\usepackage{etoolbox} % needed for headings wizardry, below

\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\thepage}
\fancyhead[RE,LO]{\myBotmark} % "RE" just for testing purposes
\pagestyle{fancy}

%%%%%%%% BEGIN WIZARDRY %%%%%%%%

\makeatletter

\@ifdefinable\@my@claim@mark{\newmarks\@my@claim@mark}
\newcommand*\myMark[1]{\marks\@my@claim@mark{#1}}
\newcommand*\myBotmark{\botmarks\@my@claim@mark}

       \patchcmd{\@begintheorem}{% search for:
        \thm@swap\swappedhead\thmhead % more specific than before
    }{% replace with:
        \myMark{#1\@ifnotempty{#2}{\ #2}\@ifnotempty{#3}{\ (#3)}}%
        \thm@swap\swappedhead\thmhead
    }    

\makeatother

%%%%%%%%  END WIZARDRY  %%%%%%%%

 \begin{document}

Denote the reals by $\mathbb{R}$.

\begin{theorem}[about \protect $\mathbb{R}$] % gives error
%\begin{theorem}[about $R$] % so would this be OK
%\begin{theorem}[about reals] % this would be OK

Big result!

\end{theorem}

\newpage

%\begin{corollary}[special case for $\mathbb{Q}$]
 \begin{corollary}[special case for $Q$]
 %\begin{corollary}[special case for rationals]

Another assertion.

\end{corollary}

\end{document}
```

The error from running pdflatex on that is:

```
...42: Undefined control sequence.
\GenericError   ...
                           #4   \errhelp \@err@   ...
l.42   \begin{theorem}[about \protect $\mathbb{R}$] 
                                          % gives error
```

**A clue to ultimate error cause?**

Comment out all reference to `fancyhdr` and comment out all the patch code related to that, but now insert

```
\usepackage{thmtools}
```

in the preamble and

```
\listoftheorems
```

in the document body. Then having `$\mathbb{R}$` in the theorem's optional argument causes *no* error in typesetting the List of Theorems — even without any `\protect` in that optional argument.

All this suggests the error stems from something in the code's "wizardry" that interacts with `amsthm` or `fancyhdr`.

Comment: try entering this as `$\protect\mathbb$`.

Comment: Nope, putting `\protect` into the optional `\begin{theorem}` argument does not eliminate the error. That's one of the things I did already try, without success; should have said that in OP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before referring you to [my previous, and now updated answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/320720/69818), allow me to draw your attention to some facts:

1. The code `\protect $\mathbb{R}$` is wrong for (at least) two reasons,
   the first being that `\protect` applies *only* to the following
   token, in this case `$`; but `$` is robust by itself, since it is a
   primitive command of TeX and, as such, an unexpandable token.
2. Even `$\protect\mathbb{R}$` would be wrong, anyway, or rather,
   useless, because `\mathbb` is already made robust by the LaTeX
   kernel.
3. `\patchcmd` takes *five* arguments:

   ```
   \patchcmd{<cmd>}{<search>}{<replace>}{<success>}{<failure>}
   ```

   where `<success>` and `<failure>` are bits of code you want to
   execute if `\patchcmd` succeeds or fails, respectively.  If you
   don’t want to execute any code, leave them empty, but you cannot
   simply omit them.  In your example, you have been very lucky that
   a `\par` and the `\makeatother` were gobbled in their place…

For your convenience, I’ll also leave here the code streamlined for use with the `amsmath` package.  I invite you to try it out: I have added `\protect` management in the `\myMark` command.  Omitting to do so in previous versions was certainly a mistake: see if it now works.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % Not necessary, but recommended.
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\usepackage{amsthm} % we have decided to go for this one
\usepackage{amsfonts}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\thepage}
\fancyhead[RE,LO]{\myBotmark} % "RE" just for testing purposes
\pagestyle{fancy}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section] % or "[chapter]", or whatever
\newtheorem{lemma}  {Lemma}  [section]
\newtheorem*{spclaim}{Special Claim}
\swapnumbers
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{defin}{Definition}[section]



%%%%%%%% BEGIN WIZARDRY %%%%%%%%

\makeatletter

\@ifdefinable\@my@claim@mark{\newmarks\@my@claim@mark}
\newcommand*\myMark[1]{% <<< MODIFIED
    \begingroup
        \let\label\relax \let\index\relax \let\glossary\relax
        \let\protect\@unexpandable@protect
        \marks\@my@claim@mark{#1}%
    \endgroup
}
\newcommand*\myBotmark{\botmarks\@my@claim@mark}

\typeout{****************************************}
\newcommand*\my@direct@mark[3]{%
    \myMark{%
        \thmname{#1}%
        \thmnumber{\thmname{\ }#2}%
        \thmnote{\ (#3)}%
    }%
}
\newcommand*\my@swapped@mark[3]{%
    \myMark{%
        \thmnumber{#2}%
        \thmname{\thmnumber{\ }#1}%
        \thmnote{\ (#3)}%
    }%
}
\patchcmd{\@begintheorem}{% search for:
    \thm@swap\swappedhead\thmhead % more specific than before
}{% replace with:
    \thm@swap\my@swapped@mark\my@direct@mark{#1}{#2}{#3}%
    \thm@swap\swappedhead\thmhead
}{% execute if succeeded:
    \typeout{>>> Made patch specific for amsthm.}
}{% execute if failed:
    \typeout{>>> Patch specific for amsthm FAILED!}
}
\typeout{****************************************}

\makeatother

%%%%%%%%  END WIZARDRY  %%%%%%%%



\begin{document}

\section{First section}

\lipsum[1]

\begin{theorem}
    This is the first theorem of the first section.
\end{theorem}

\lipsum[2]

\begin{theorem}
    This is the second theorem of the first section.
\end{theorem}

\begin{theorem}[Donald Duck and~$\mathbb{Q}$]
    This is the third theorem of the first section.
\end{theorem}

\begin{spclaim}
    This is a special claim.
\end{spclaim}

\lipsum[3-16]

\begin{theorem}
    This is the fourth theorem of the first section.
\end{theorem}

\begin{defin}[Something new]
    This is the first definition of the first section.
\end{defin}

\begin{defin}
    This is the second definition of the first section.
\end{defin}

\lipsum[17]

\begin{lemma}
    This is the first lemma of the first section.
\end{lemma}

\lipsum[18]

\begin{theorem}
    This is the fifth theorem of the first section.
\end{theorem}

\lipsum[19-20]

\begin{lemma}[Uncle Scrooge and~$\mathbb{R}$]
    This is the second lemma of the first section.
\end{lemma}

\lipsum[21-32]

\begin{theorem}
    This is the sixth theorem of the first section.
\end{theorem}

\lipsum[33-36]

\begin{theorem}
    This is the seventh theorem of the first section.
\end{theorem}

\begin{lemma}
    This is the third lemma of the first section.
\end{lemma}

\begin{theorem}[Mickey Mouse and~$\mathbb{C}$]
    This is the eighth theorem of the first section.
\end{theorem}

\lipsum[37-40]

\begin{theorem}
    This is the ninth theorem of the first section.
\end{theorem}

\lipsum[41-48]

\begin{defin}
    This is the third definition of the first section.
\end{defin}

\lipsum[49-64]

\begin{theorem}[The last one]
    This is the tenth theorem of the first section.
\end{theorem}

\lipsum[65-80]

\begin{lemma}
    This is the fourth lemma of the first section.
\end{lemma}

\begin{lemma}
    This is the fifth lemma of the first section.
\end{lemma}

\begin{lemma}
    This is the sixth lemma of the first section.
\end{lemma}

\begin{lemma}
    This is the seventh lemma of the first section.
\end{lemma}

\begin{lemma}
    This is the eighth lemma of the first section.
\end{lemma}

\begin{lemma}
    This is the ninth lemma of the first section.
\end{lemma}

\begin{lemma}[Deep breath]
    This is the tenth lemma of the first section.
\end{lemma}

\lipsum[81-84]

\begin{lemma}
    This is the eleventh lemma of the first section.
\end{lemma}

\begin{lemma}
    This is the twelfth lemma of the first section.
\end{lemma}

\begin{lemma}
    This is the thirteenth lemma of the first section.
\end{lemma}

\begin{lemma}
    This is the fourteenth lemma of the first section.
\end{lemma}

\begin{lemma}
    This is the fifteenth lemma of the first section.
\end{lemma}

\begin{lemma}[Hexadecimal deep breath]
    This is the sixteenth lemma of the first section.
\end{lemma}

% \lipsum[85-96]

\end{document}
```

Please note that I intend to remove this answer as soon as you notify me that you have read it: it is actually a duplicate of my other answer to which it refers.

Comment: @murray: It looks like this answer, streamlined for `amsthm`, meets with more success than the other one… :-)  Which one should I remove?

Comment: I much prefer the "streamlined" version specifically for `amsthm`, since that's the package I always use for theorem-like environments. I do note that with my actual book-length multi-file document (using `memoir` as documentclass), the marks that include the theorem number & name will not appear at all in a chapter when the 1st instance of a theorem-like environment is not until the 2nd or 3rd pages of the chapter -- unless that theorem-like environment is actually "theorem" rather than "definition". I have tried to reproduce this in a simple, single-file MWE but have not yet succeeded.